# Number of people killed during the Mahabharata war

Tags: mahabharata

The Adi Parva of Mahabharata describes Kaurava Army to be 11 Akshauhinis and Pandava Army to be 7 Akshauhinis. That's almost over 1.8 million soldiers.

Does Mahabharata give any details on the number of lives lost during the war?

Comment: @iammilind : Thanks for referring to the original question. That does answer the question and I can go ahead and close this one. But the count of people who dies is way too inflated, that many people did not even participate in the war.

Comment: You are right about inflated number. My intention to offer a duplicate was that let all the members answer in the old Qn with correct figure. Since that Qn is little broad, you may also ask Mod to merge your Qn with it (if you want). Personally I think billion people didn't die. It could be few millions (< 10 mn) at max.

Answer (score 3):

From [Chapter 26](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m11/m11025.htm) of Stri Parva, Mahabharata,

> The royal sage Dhritarashtra, however, restraining the grief that arises from folly, enquired of Yudhishthira the just, saying, ‘If, O son of Pandu, thou knowest it, tell me the number of those that have fallen in this battle, as also of those that have escaped with life!’ "Yudhishthira answered, ‘One billion 660 million and 20,000 men have fallen in this battle. Of the heroes that have escaped, the number is 240,165.’